# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, url

I know there is probably a simple answer to this but what am I doing wrong? I get **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)** on the 8th line of code.

```
import UIKit

class Website: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webViewWebsite: UIWebView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.mindenefree.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webViewWebsite.loadRequest(request)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, doesn't look like an issue with your code.

Comment: Which is the 8th line?

Comment: webViewWebsite.loadRequest(request)

Comment: Is it the `webViewWebsite ` correctly assigned to a `UIWebView` in the corresponding xib/storyboard? If yes, try deleting it and assign it again.

Comment: It also says **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**

Comment: Is the `@IBOutlet webViewWebsite` property correctly linked to a WebView in your storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears (after your comment) that the `webViewWebsite` isn't correctly linked to any `UIWebView` in the corresponding xib or storyboard.

So try linking the `@IBOutlet` again to the corresponding `UIWebView` in the xib/storyboard again, or if you didn't do that yet try doing that now. It should work after that. Cause your code looks ok.